# OnCheckedChangeListener fires when scrolling down

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I faced with a weird problem.  I have an android application and it contains activity that includes `ListViewAdapter`. Each element contains a `checkbox`.
And I've the following code -

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CheckBox check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);
    if(check.getTag() == null) {
        check.setTag(position);
        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    }
   check.setChecked(holders.get(position).isChecked);              
}

private OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {  
          holders.get((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).isChecked = isChecked;
      }
};
```

And when I scroll my `listview` down my `OnCheckedChangeListener` fires and reset my `checkbox` if it was set. Why does it happend? I excpeted OnCheckedChangeListener  will be triggered when I click `checkbox` manually or call **setChecked** programmatically but it does when i scroll down too. Why?

Comment: Likely it's view recycling going on in your adapter but the code you posted can't be your actual code.

Comment: post the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Karn is correct, it is getting recycled, so when scrolling, it generates the view and:

```
check.setChecked(holders.get(position).isChecked);
```

makes it so your listener is called every time you scroll because you set your listener to listen when the check is changed. Change your setOnCheckedChangeListener to setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll `getView` method is called due to view recycling behavior of adapter. and `setChecked` method will call which triggers  `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: I am sorry but I can not understand why setChecked method should be called when i scrolling? I am just scrolling but i don't check or uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: For You need to understand Adapter mechanism:
Go through this link :http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Comment: Thank tou it is good article but in it i haven't found an answer for my question - why setChecked method should be called when i scrolling?

Comment: If you check that article properly, It stated that getView will call every time you scroll your list to add new rows and remove old rows. and so that you setChecked method called everytime